# Automation of 3rd party App in IOS

Tags: ios, automation

as mentioned in the title. Is there any possibility to schedule or automate certain steps/tasks within a 3rd party app on the iphone? 
The automated app doesn't necessarily have to be run in background, whereas it would be more comfortable of course.

I am grateful for any idea or hint. Whether programming, scripting or maybe an existing app which could do that.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is you can only automate tests on your own apps. There are SaaS vendors where you can test your own apps, but you can't download an app via the store for remote testing like that.